# Different pages under different tabs in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a tabcontrol in my mainwindow and I have tabs like users, transactions, etc. I created a page individually to show under each tab. But I'm not sure how to plugin each page under each tab. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Display aeach `Page` using a [`Frame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.frame?view=netframework-4.8#examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be not to use pages at all.

Go with usercontrols instead.

Pages require a frame to host them and that is quite a hefty container with memory overheads. A usercontrol can be hosted in any contentcontrol and hence go directly in a tab item.

```
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Departments">
                <local:UserControl1/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Finance">
                <local:UserControl2/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

Try putting a page in one instead.

You will get an error:

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Page can have only Window or Frame as parent.*

So you'd have to put a frame in each tabitem and then your page inside that.

Then you'd want to set properties on the frame to hide the navigation you're not going to want to use.

Which is pointless overhead.

Pages were useful for xbap - wpf in a browser - which would be a bad idea nowadays.

Or

If you want a "wizard" style piece of UI where the user goes through a series of steps inputting data and doing stuff. Often you want them to be able to go back. Eventually, they commit the changes in one go at the end of the set of steps and it does it's stuff.

Other than that, Pages are a bad choice in a wpf desktop app.